# Image save on button click throws unhandled Exception error in WP7 and also saves duplicate image

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to save image in WP7 phone on a button click 
Following is the code

```
 private void wallpaper_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        String imageName ="temjpeg";      I

        // Create virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
        var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (myStore.FileExists(temjpeg))
        {
            myStore.DeleteFile(temjpeg);
        }

        IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(imageName);


        // Create a stream out of the sample JPEG file.
        // For [Application Name] in the URI, use the project name that you entered in                               the previous steps. Also TestImage.jpg is an example,
        //you must enter your JPEG filename if it is different.
        StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri("some String",UriKind.Relative);
        sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

        // Create a new WriteableBitmap object and set it to the JPEG stream.
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);


        // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
        // SaveJpeg(WriteableBitmap bitmap, Stream targetStream, int targetWidth, int targetHeight, int orientation, int quality)
        Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
        myFileStream.Close();


        // Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
        myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(temjpeg, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();

         Picture pic = library.SavePicture(imageName, myFileStream);
        myFileStream.Close();
         }
```

But this code throws  InvalidOperationException on  line : Picture pic = library.SavePicture(imageName, myFileStream);
What could be the problem?..
after the exception problem was solved,now the image is saving multiple times if save button is clicked multiple times.Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this on the emulator as SavePicture will not work on the emulator, only on the actual phone itself.

Comment: No i am doing it on Windows Phone 7 device.

Comment: Are you tring it with the USB cable connected?  If so, try it without.

Comment: thanks a lot man..u saved my life :)..but one more thing ..now the image is saving as many times as i click the button ..but i want it to besaved once only and do nothing if already save.

Comment: Can you not simply set a bool flag when you save it the first time, and then check to see if that is true whenever you press again.

Comment: Actually having a list of images from which one at a time is displayed and then if want,one can save it..so if i put a flag then it will never allow any other image to be saved

Comment: When you are saving the picture, can you not then simply check if the picture name already exists in the file path?  I'm not that familiar with WP.

Comment: I am actually doing that in the beginning only by checking the Isolated storage if u see the code.the Temp jpeg is the name of the image